# How to select data in one table where its reference date is between dates in a different table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables: a campaign table and a transactions table. The campaign table contains the names of merchants and dates when they're having sale campaigns, like so:

```
start_date     end_date     merchant     campaign_name
2019-09-01     2019-09-04   Store A      Holiday Discount
2019-10-30     2019-11-01   Store B      Halloweenfest
```

The transactions table contains raw transactions, like so:

```
trx_no     trx_date     customer_id     product     price     merchant
1          2019-09-01   182631231       Stocking    6.50      Store A
2          2019-09-06   184234225       Helmet      9.20      Store A 
3          2019-10-06   185362289       Pen         2.10      Store B 
4          2019-10-31   189988123       Hat         4.30      Store B
```

Since store A only conducted their campaign between 1-4 Sept, and store B only conducted their campaign between 30 Oct and 1 Nov, how do I only return transactions which were conducted during sale campaigns by joining those two tables? I can join based on merchant, but how do I only pull data that's between `start_date` and `end_date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` and put the date conditions in the `on` clause:

```
select t.*, c.campaign_name
from campaign c join
     transactions t
     on t.merchant = c.merchant and
        t.trx_date between c.start_date and c.end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and put the date range filter in the `where` clause. The reason for putting date check in the `where` clause is, `join` is more optimized to work with equality conditions. We can then filter the datasets based on range filters.

The query would look like this:

```
SELECT 
    b.*, a.campaign_name
FROM 
    campaign a 
INNER JOIN 
    transactions b
ON 
    a.merchant = b.merchant 
WHERE 
    b.trx_date BETWEEN a.start_date AND a.end_date;
```